# How would you make a wizard system with PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, wizard

I need to create a wizard system for one of my projects and this is currently how I handle it right now.

```
/*
   Just pseudo functions
*/

function wizard_start()
{
    //Fill the table with default values, set isVisible column to 0
}

function wizard_step_1()
{
    //Update necessary columns (e.g Name, sirname)
}

function wizard_step_2()
{
    //Update necessary columns (e.g Date, Type)
}

...

function wizard_final()
{
    //Do the last touches and update isVisible to 1 so it will appear on website
}
```

I keep our current step in session. Like;

```
isset($_session['step2_completed'])
    $this->wizard_step_3();

isset($_session['step3_completed'])
    $this->wizard_step_4();

...
```

Responses are made via `XMLHttpRequest` and expects a data in JSON format. If JSON returns true, Javascript loads the next piece of wizard. (Usually HTML forms for different tasks.)

I'm wondering if there are better and more good-practice wizard alternatives. For example, I don't know if keeping current step in session is a good or a bad practice way.

Basically, how would you design such task yourself, trying to use best practices as much as possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a workflow like the one in ezComponents - http://ezcomponents.org/docs/api/latest/introduction_Workflow.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping the current step in the session variable is fine, with the following good practice points:

1. A wizard is usually a method of getting information from the user in a step-by-step fashion. In most cases, the use can opt out or cancel at any stage. In your solution you are updating columns in a database at each step. While I appreciate that you have `isVisible` to prevent half-filled records from causing problems, usually you would store this information somewhere temporary (such as variables) and only commit the complete record when the user hits "finish". Of course, the exception to this is if loss of the user's input is an issue. Eg. in an email site we would not want loss of the session to mean loss of a draft email.
2. Further to the above point you may actually want to store the in-progress values in the session variable. That way your application remains unaffected until an "atomic" commit at the final stage.
3. When storing the current stage of the session, use a sequential flag (ie. an integer which indicates the last completed step as opposed to `step_x_completed`). That way you have less state variables and less opportunity for error.
4. Security is another matter, you'd need to provide more information about the environment your application is in before we can discuss security considerations.